# WPF window resizing and ActualWidth / ActualHeight values

Tags: wpf, xaml, resize, window

In my WPF project, I have a `Canvas` in which I do some drawings. Following the code for the Window:

```
<Window x:Name="PropertyDefinition_Window" x:Class="PushOverStraus7.PropertyDefinitionWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="PropertyDefinitionWindow" Height="360" Width="730" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <TreeView SelectedItemChanged="Treeview_PropertyDefinition_SelectedItemChanged">
        <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">
            <TreeViewItem />
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem"/>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
    <Canvas x:Name="Canvas_LongitudinalBarRectanglePage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="251" Margin="255,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="285" Background="Black">            
    </Canvas> 
    <Button x:Name="NewButton" Content="Nuovo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,277,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" Click="NewButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="DuplicateButton" Content="Duplica" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="85,277,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45"/>

</Grid>
```

I want that, resizing the Window, the `Canvas` size changes accordingly. Then, I need to have `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the Canvas resized to use them for drawing alghorithm.
How can I have the automatical resize of the Canvas and how to get values described above?
Thanks for your help

EDIT:
I've changed the question as asked

Comment: Please show also the code where you set the Frame Content. And why do you need a Frame at all? You don't seem to be using Frame Navigation.

Comment: Frame is not so useful to show because it does not affect Canvas behaviour. As you can read in my edit, I remove the Canvas from the Page (and from Frame consequently), so Canvas is clearly inside the Window with defined width and height

Comment: Maybe you reduce your question to what you are *actually* doing. Remove those things that are no longer relevant, and please add the relevant code-behind parts.

Answer (score 0):

With the following XAML the Canvas will automatically be resized when the Window size changes.

```
<Window ...>
    <Frame>
        <Frame.Content>
            <Page>
                <Canvas>
                    ...
                </Canvas>
            </Page>
        </Frame.Content>
    </Frame>
</Window>
```

Comment: It turns the `Frame` inherits the size of the `Window`? Or both?

Comment: I can't test it, because I have two different XAML to manage, one for the window and one for the page...I set the frame content via code, because it changes programmatically, selecting an item in a treeview. So I can't use XAML above

Comment: Then why don't you post the relevant parts of your code in your question?

Comment: you are right...sorry I was not so clear...I put the code in the post